# Create .xib launch screen in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, launch-screen

I am trying to create launch screen in an older iOS App using **Xcode 8**. I need `.xib` launch screen but Xcode is creating Launch `Screen.storyboard`. Could anyone suggest please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add your desired launch screen .xib file to your project, and in your **General** section in "**App icons and launch images**" subsection select in launch screen file your desired xib file

**Creating the xib file (in top menu go to File -> Menu -> File..)**
[image]

**Setting the xib file as launch screen**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How I can add xib file?

Comment: @Yas check my answer and let me know if you need further orientations

Comment: Yes I checked that option. I want to ask that how I can create LaunchScreen.xib? From Xcode I am trying to File-> New -> Launch Screen but it is creating .storyboard file but I want .xib file.

Comment: @Yas instead of select launch Screen in the template selection you need select View, I can post an image

Comment: @Yas any xib file can be used for LaunchScreen

Comment: @Yas What is the problem if you've .storyboard instead of .xib for launch screen?

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you for the suggestion. I did that and got launch screen but app doesn't work after that and stop with the error "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target"

Comment: Did you set a class to your created xib? is not needed maybe that is the error now @Yas this works was tested, try if you want with an empty project

Comment: @Yas also check if you accidentally change your app main interface

Comment: @ReinierMelian No I didn't set any class.. Sorry, I am not sure about this as I am not much aware with iOS app development.

If I remove the launch screen, then app works fine.

Comment: @Yas can you post your code in some dropbox or github or google drive? i can review and setting up your xib file as launch screen if your want to

Comment: @ReinierMelian posting all code won't be feasible for me due to some limitations. I really appreciate your intension and help. Could you please suggest me something to check and fix it?

Comment: Its works for an example project I can post an example an you can find the issue in your real project? @Yas

Comment: @ReinierMelian Okay, I can check that. Is there any other step involved for creating launch screen. As I only created a new view and added image in that and then selected launch screen file.

Comment: @Yas that is all, no more steps are required, i will post an example on github

Comment: Thank you @ReinierMelian

Comment: @Yas let me know, I had pushed again to the repo with an image in the launchScreen I think you talk something about that

Comment: Yes I checked the App and it is working fine. but in my case I am getting error after launch screen "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target". There might be something wrong.

Comment: @Yas google this "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target" there are some many answers for that issue check